# Field values changing position

Tags: php, html, database, forms

I have this form where you edit user information. The problem is the values of the fields move.

[image]

As you can see the email moved to the address.

Here is my db schema:

[image]

I noticed that when I try to edit the "renderForm" everything moves. I just can't figure out the pattern. Can you guys help me?

Here's my the sourcecode:

```html
function renderForm($fullname = '', $username ='', $error = '', $id = '', $email = '', $address = '', $contact = '', $gender = '', $password = '', $user_levels = '', $date = '', $picture = '', $sickleave = '', $vacationleave = '')
```

Comment: how do you call the `renderForm()` function? most likely you appended values to the wrong field

Comment: @Akintunde007 What do you mean how do I call?

Comment: How do you call the `renderForm()` function? Where is it invoked? Did you write the above code?

Comment: @Akintunde007 I'm not sure by what you meant sorry

Comment: All you have done is define a function,but how do you use it? How is the edit form being rendered?

Comment: It may not have anything to do with that way that your database is set up. You may just be assigning the email address value to a variable when you are meaning to assign the address. Akintunde007 wants to see where the `renderForm()` function appears in your code. Where is your page running the `renderForm()` function? Better yet, can you paste in the contents of the `renderForm()` function itself?

Comment: we need to see the rest of your php code where you validate the form